# WinForms - Keep child form open in case user cancels closing parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background:**

I am creating a WinForms app using C# 4.0 and VS2013.  My app has a main form named `ParentForm` and a secondary form named `ChildForm`.  The application follows an Model-View-Presenter design, so I want my presenter class `P` to control all the form opening, closing, button clicks, and generally anything the user requests.  (Both forms are actually abstracted behind "view" interfaces, but the problem is specifically with the WinForms implementation, so let's ignore the interfaces.)

**Problem:**

Currently `P` is handling `FormClosing` events for both `ParentForm` and `ChildForm`, and calling `Form.Close` or `Form.Dispose` if it determines that the user is allowed to close these forms.

The problem I'm having is if `ChildForm` is open and the user clicks the 'X' button on `ParentForm`.  In this scenario, `FormClosing` is called first on `ChildForm`, then on `ParentForm`.  `P` doesn't have any way of knowing whether the user clicked 'X' on `ChildForm` (which `P` should react to by closing `ChildForm`), or the user clicked 'X' on `ParentForm` (which `P` should react to by confirming if the user really wants to exit, before closing any forms).

**Questions:**

Is there a way to tell if `FormClosing` is being called in reaction to a parent form closing?

Is there any way to treat the 'X' button like a normal button?

Is there a way to prevent child form closes until after the parent form's `FormClosing` event (and possible user cancellation)?

Comment: Please clarify the term "child form" - e.g. MdiChild, owned form or? What does `e.CloseReason` show in one or another case?

Comment: @Ivan - Sorry, by "child" I meant `ChildForm.Owner == ParentForm`.  I did not know about `e.CloseReason`; this gives me all the information I need.  When the user tries to close `ChildForm` its `CloseReason.UserClosing` , when the user tries to exit the program its `CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ivan - Post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which according to MSDN

> Gets a value that indicates why the form is being closed.

See the [CloseReason Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason(v=vs.110).aspx) values, in particular `FormOwnerClosing` and `MdiFormClosing`.